# drawInRect performance too slow

Tags: objective-c, ios

What I'm doing is merge 2 images into single image.

Here is the code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(1024, 768));

[image1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 768)];
[image2 drawInRect:CGRectMake(512, 0, 512, 768)];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

But drawInRect seems too slow.

Is there faster way to merge images?

Comment: Why are you trying to merge two images? And what does "too slow" mean? You're pushing around a good number of pixels.

Comment: The fastest way of merging images is to avoid merging them when you do not need to. For example, you can merge once, cache the result, and re-use the image from then on, until one of the pre-merge images changes.

Comment: @KevinBallard Because i need it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight well, I'm asking about improving the performance when i call it, not avoiding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 0 - Make sure you draw only when you need to draw, and only what you need to draw.

---

## Option 1

If you know the destination size (perhaps `self.frame.size`?), you can create one image from the two source images (flatten) at the destination size *and* avoid interpolation. So that could:

1. Reduce the memory you need
2. Reduce the number of images you must draw
3. Avoid interpolation (High CPU if you want it to look good)
4. Look better - the composite can use High Quality interpolation.

Of course, this only makes sense when the composite varies at a frequency lower than it must be drawn.

## Option 2

Even if you want two images and you know their sizes will not change, just resize them to the size they must be drawn at (well, monitor your memory usage if you are enlarging them).

## Option 3

If that's not an option, you could alter the `CGContext`'s state, and reduce interpolation quality. If you're used to similar CALayer transformations, you would probably be satisfied with low quality or no interpolation.

Comment: Did the OP edit the question? This seems to be answering a different problem (where does interpolation come into this?). I just hit a problem discovering that iOS drawInRect is INCREDIBLY SLOW (it would be faster to draw the image pixel by pixel, save it to disk, reload it as a new file (from disk!), and display it ... than to call drawInRect:. That's insane)

Comment: @Adam no, the question wasn't edited. interpolation of many colors is what's used when stretching/resizing. the point is that resizing is time consuming, but there are quality options and ways to avoid and minimize the speed of resizing.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is not implement -drawRect: at all, but instead have two CALayers with your two images as their contents, then put one in front of the other. Not sure that would be faster, but I think it's likely (since CA could then handle the drawing asynchronously, on the GPU).